# L2TP (xl2tpd) IP Address Allocation

Tags: dhcp, l2tp, point-to-point-protocol

I’m making my own study of different ways to establish tunnels between Debian server (LNS) and Android OS (LAC). In case of L2TP without any encryption, LACs should routing traffic through ppp tunnel in accordance with a list of networks. I’ve got that I can control routing on LACs because LNS doesn’t send routes to LACs, and I’m going to use DHCP option for doing that. But I want to understand how LNS allocates and transmits IP addresses to LACs. I don’t see any information about that when sniff the traffic and can’t find that in L2TP or PPP RFCs and xl2tpd and pppd documentations.

Answer (score 0):

PPP allocates IP addresses in according to secrets.conf file or a radius server. And sends that information to LAC in PPP IPCP messages.